# Build layer that doesn't contain dojo/**/*.js files

Tags: build, dojo

I am attempting to create a layer for my project.  I would like the layer to contain 
`myProject/controllers/MainApp` and all of its dependencies that are in the `myProject`
package.  I do not want to include any dojo, dijit or otherPackages in my layer.

This is what I have so far:

```
var profile = (function() {    

    var locationPrefix = "something";
    return {        

        basePath: "../src",
        releaseDir: "../dojoRelease",
        releaseName: "lib",
        action: "release",
        packages: [
            {
                name: 'dojo',
                location: locationPrefix + '/dojo/dojo'
            }, {
                name: 'dijit',
                location: locationPrefix + '/dojo/dijit'
            }, {
                ...
            }, {
                name: 'myProject',
                location: 'myProject',
                destLocation: 'myProject'
            }
        ],

        layers: {          
            "myProject": {
                include: ["myProject/controllers/MainApp"],
                // QUESTION: How can I use exclude to not include all dojo modules?
                // tried several things but none seem to work.  Can't find any doc 
                // on what exclude takes as input.  
                // exclude: ["dojo/dojo"],
                boot: false,
                customBase: true
            }
        }    
    };
})();
```

The problem is that when I look at my main.js.uncompressed.js it contins lots of things that are not
in `myProject`.  These are the first few lines in the main.js.uncompressed.js file:

```
require({cache:{
'dojo/parser':function(){
define([
    "require", "./_base/kernel", "./_base/lang", "./_base/array", "./_base/config", "./dom", "./_base/window",
        "./_base/url", "./aspect", "./promise/all", "./date/stamp", "./Deferred", "./has", "./query", "./on", "./ready"
], function(require, dojo, dlang, darray, config, dom, dwindow, _Url, aspect, all, dates, Deferred, has, query, don, ready){

    // module:
    //      dojo/parser

    new Date("X"); // workaround for #11279, new Date("") == NaN

    // data-dojo-props etc. is not restricted to JSON, it can be any javascript
    function myEval(text){
        return eval("(" + text + ")");
    }
```

The source for:

- dijit/_Widget
- dojo/Stateful
- dijit/Destroyable
- dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin
- dijit/a11yclick

and many other files also show up in the main.js.uncompressed.js file.

How can I limit the main.js.uncompressed.js file to be only the files
in my project?  Thanks!

---

**Update:** I tried removing dojo, dijit, etc from the list of packages.  This causes the main.js.uncompressed.js to generate more or less correctly, the compiler then hangs on generating the minified file.  There are also many errors like this:

```
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myProject/controllers/someFile; dependency: dojo/_base/declare
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myProject/controllers/someFile; dependency: dojo/_base/lang
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myProject/controllers/someFile; dependency: dojo/Deferred
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I look at my main.js.uncompressed.js it
>   contins lots of things that are not in myProject.

They might not be *in* myProject but are you sure you're not making use of any of them anywhere? For example in the output you include it shows that someFile is using dojo/_base/declare function. If you're using declare at the start of your someFile module then you'll need dojo in the layer to be able to run it.

```
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myProject/controllers/someFile; dependency: dojo/_base/declare
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myProject/controllers/someFile; dependency: dojo/_base/lang
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myProject/controllers/someFile; dependency: dojo/Deferred
```

> Can't find any doc on what exclude takes as input.

It's the same format as the include - an array of string modules - see here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/

Using the boot property will also included some dojo code in your layer as you're telling the builder to make your layer bootable so it has to include the dojo code for module loading to let you load youre other modules.